# How to go to UITabBarController after clicking the respective UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

[image: how to go on home page on login button click]

how to go on home page on login button click

```
- (IBAction)loginClick:(id)sender {
    HomeVC *secondView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Comment: You can create a segue from `LoginVC` to tabbarcontroller. Or make `tabbarcontroller` as root and preset `LoginVC` over it and dismiss on login success.

Comment: you are creating a wrong view controller. You need to create TabbarController and push it. Tabbarcontroller contains HomeVC and the Other View controller.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to set your login page as a Root controller and when you successfully logged in then you have to change your root controller and make your Tab Bar as a root controller.
Perform this code in your AppDelegate and call these method on your login and logout page.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) UITabBar *tabBar;
@property(nonatomic,strong) UITabBarController *tabBarController;


- (void)Login{

  [self.window setRootViewController:nil];
   UIStoryboard *MainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone"                                                             bundle: nil];
   UITabBarController *bar= (UITabBarController*)[MainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbar"];
   self.window.rootViewController=bar;

}

 -(void)Logout
  {
   // self.window.rootViewController = nil;
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController*vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homepage"];
   // Homepage *controller = [[Homepage alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
  }
```

Comment: How can i set login page as a root controller and what is property window

Answer (score 0):

Implement didFinishLaunching method this way :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];

BOOL isLogin = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"IS_LOGIN"];
if (isLogin == YES)
{
    rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainHomeTabView"];
}
self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

And set TRUE when you pressed login button

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender
{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"IS_LOGIN"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

TabListViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainHomeTabView"];
AppDelegate *appDelagate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelagate.window.rootViewController = vc;
}
```